# CSS Style Sheet not working when opening file in browser

Tags: css

Style sheet affects my pages that are online, but not when I open it in a browser. My style sheet is called myStyle.css but when I link it to a different page by using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myStyle.css">
```

And it didn't work. It does work when I upload it to godaddy, but not when I just open it in a browser.

Comment: Are your web page and stylesheet in the same folder?

Comment: Open console and see if there is an issue while including the file

Comment: Change `href="/myStyle.css"` to `href="./myStyle.css"`

Comment: You need to show your folder structure, specifically where your CSS file is in relation to your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks Dima. Works now